# How to Retrieve data within specified dates from Multiple Tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, date-range

I want to fetch those users that not performed action_id 110 within specified date range

Date Range
From  - 2014-04-01
To - 2014-08-08

**tbl_user**

```
userid  name    email                       db_add_date
1       steve   stevemartin144@gmail.com    2014-04-08 01:11:37
2       mark    mark04@gmail.com            2014-07-18 07:10:01
3       nelson  nel02@yahoo.com             2014-05-28 14:02:04
4       andrew  amaria@gmail.com            2014-01-12 10:42:39
5       himou   hil_man@gmail.com           2014-03-22 23:32:04
```

**tbl_points**

```
id  userid  action_id  points
1   2       110        10
2   1       100        45
3   1       110        10
4   4       104        25
5   3       100        28
```

Result will be

```
-------------
name    email
-------------
nelson  nel02@yahoo.com
andrew  amaria@gmail.com
himou   hil_man@gmail.com
```

Comment: Use a LEFT JOIN and check with IS NULL

Answer (score 3):

You should really have a `DATETIME` on the `tbl_points`, or maybe `tbl_action`, (instead of)/(as well as) the `tbl_user` for this, but using your current structure:

```
   SELECT t.name, t.email 
     FROM tbl_user tu
LEFT JOIN tbl_points tp 
       ON tu.userid = tp.userid  
      AND tp.action_id = 110
    WHERE tu.db_add_date NOT BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND '2014-08-08'
      AND tp.id IS NULL
```

Comment: That's an interesting intepretation of the date range. I didn't get it myself. But your query won't return nelson. I think the desired result isn't clear. Remove your (instead of), it's needed to get, where had done this action.

Comment: @Vmai Good point, this is the logic the OP has described.. it appears that nelson has performed action 110 in the disallowed date range. I'm not sure why he is in the desired response.. perhaps there is a datetime in the action table that we are unaware of.

Answer (score 2):

```
select u.name,u.email from tbl_user u
left join tbl_points p on p.usrid=u.userid and p.action_id=110
where u.db_add_date between '2014-04-01' and '2014-08-08' 
and p.id is null
```

Comment: Looks good, but I don't know why OP wants to have andrew and himou in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you

```
Select u.name, u.email from tbl_user u, tbl_points p 
where p.action_id!=110
AND u.db_add_date BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND '2014-08-08'
group by u.userid;
```

and the result to the query will be

```
NAME    EMAIL
steve   stevemartin144@gmail.com
mark    mark04@gmail.com
nelson  nel02@yahoo.com
```

You can have a look on this [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f336e/7)

Answer (score -1):

Something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_user A
INNER JOIN tbl_points B ON A.userid   = B.userid  
WHERE (A.db_add_date BETWEEN ' 2014-04-01' AND '2014-08-08') 
AND (B.action_id <> 110)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
select tu.name,tu.email from tbl_users tu
inner join tbl_points tp on tu.user_id=tp.user_id
where date(tu.db_add_date) between 2014-04-01 and 2014-08-08
and tp.action_id <> 110
```

Comment: Try to explain your answer.

Comment: Because this will pick users who DID  perform action 110 - as long as they also performed other actions